# Php how to count this?

Tags: php, math, count, numbers

I have `likes variable` and `dislikes variable`, how should I change it to rating from 0 to 5 ?

Example:

1. `0 Likes - 0 Dislikes` = 0 Rating
2. `1 Likes - 0 Dislikes` = 5 Rating
3. `5 Likes - 5 Dislikes` = 2.5 Rating

Thanks alot ...

Answer (score 2):

5 * likes / (likes + dislikes)

**UPD:** Adding here from comment to preserve formatting:

```
if dislikes is 0:
    if likes is 0:
        0
    else:
        5
else:
    5 * likes / (likes + dislikes)
```

Comment: What about 0 - 0 ? 5 * 0 / (0 + 0)

Comment: you should handle the 0-case in another way anyway since to say it has a 0-reating just because it has no rating is a bit wrong in my opinion.

Comment: Handling zeros is just a simple special cases:

`if dislikes is 0:
    if likes is 0:
        0
    else
        5
else
    5 * likes / (likes + dislikes)`

Comment: `return ($likes || $dislikes) ? 5 * $likes / ($likes + $dislikes) : 0;`